# Meaning of "generalization"? in math

Tags: numerical-methods, terminology, signal-processing, interpolation

What is the meaning of word "generalization"? Please kindly explain in simple words

For example in wikipedia article of interpolation, in sub heading "polynomial interpolation " a line is written

Polynomial interpolation is a generalization of linear interpolation

What does it means? Polynomial interpolation is a sub-branch of the main branch linear interpolation? Or its opposite?

Another example from a text of signal processing:
"FIR filter is a generalization of the idea of a running average "

Comment: A linear function is a specific kind of polynomial function (a polynomial of degree one) so a polynomial is a "generalization" of a linear function.  I have no idea what and "FIR filter" is and probably and am not very good on "running averages" but the fact that "FIR filter is a generalization of the idea of a running average" tells me that a running average is a specific kind of FIR filter.  Saying that "A is a generalization of B" means that B is a subset of A

Comment: It means that linear interpolation is a subbranch of polynomial interpolation. In other words, linear interpolation is a special case of the more flexible polynomial interpolation branch. This is the same as saying that polynomial interpolation is a generalization of linear interpolation. 

This way of phrasing things is common when the simpler example (linear interpolation) is introduced earlier in curriculum.

Comment: It means that a line is also a polynomial, i.e. one of degree one. Thus, the particular concept on line can be subsumed under the **more general** concept of polynomial curve.

Comment: Another way to say it is that linear interpolation is a special case of polynomial interpolation.

Comment: @user247327 : (What you never wanted to know:) FIR - Finite Impulse Response, a.k.a. convolution with a finite sequence. In opposition to IIR - Infinite ~, most commonly the solution of a convolution equation $a*y=b*x$ for $y$ with finite sequences $a,b$.

Comment: @Lutz then do your last comment says IIR mean convolution with an infinite sequence?

Comment: @Man : Yes, as far as that is defined, as any result value is the result of an infinite sum. So you need to talk about function spaces like the absolutely summable sequences...

Answer (score 2):

Theorem $A$ is a generalization of Theorem $B$ if the result in $B$ is a special case of Theorem $A$. For example:

> Theorem $A$: Every integer divisible by $2$ and $3$ is also divisible by $6$.
>
> Theorem $B$: $12$ is divisible by $6$.

Theorem $B$ is a special case of Theorem $A$ when we let our integer to be $12$.

Another example:

> Theorem $A$: Given $n+1$ points $(x_i,y_i)$ there is a polynomial of degree $n$ which passes through them.
>
> Theorem $B$: Given $2$ points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ there is a linear polynomial  which passes through them.

Theorem $B$ is a special case of Theorem $A$ when $n=1$.

The same applies to definitions as well. Definition C generalizes Definition D if the latter is a special case of the former.

Comment: What you wrote here is true, but "polynomial interpolation" isn't a theorem, so I don't think your answer covers everything that the OP was asking about.